# Facebook SDK iOS - User photos doesn't retrieving in release build but works perfectly in Debug build.

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ios9.3

I am facing a weird bug with Facebook SDK. When i trying to request user photos from the SDK it works perfect with Debug mode. When i tried with Release mode it fails to retrieve the photos(But still works with iPad 4,iPhone 5 and old devices). I doubt whether the issue is with arm64. Moreover my App status is live and it is available for public.

Comment: Do the users testing this have a role in the app? If not, did you get the permission reviewed by Facebook already?

Comment: @CBroe Yes facebook reviewed and i got permissions for user_photos. App is live on the app store now and anybody can check it now.

Comment: you don't have sufficient information posted. you need let us know which SDK you are using and which API ?

Comment: @KunalBalani I am using FBSDKLoginKIT 4.11.0

Comment: Are you logged in as the same user and has the user granted your app `user_photos` permission? One way to verify this to grab the access token of the logged in user and use the access token debugger to check if you have the permission under 'Scopes' https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/access_token

Answer (score 1):

In your `Build Settings` of your Pods Project, or FacebookSDK Target, try setting up the `Build Active Architecture Only` to `No`

[image]

Comment: I double checked it. It is set to "NO" (Default).